# Failed finding GRUB drives of recently installed distros on another drive, edit device.map?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, grub2, grub2-mkconfig

I am running Linux Mint 19.1 on a Samsung 860 EVO 500 GB (dev/sdb) along with Windows 10 on it and recently added a Crucial MX500 1TB (dev/sda) to try out and use more distros, both of them are partitionated. After that installing GRUB on the MX500 failed while installing the other distros (Kali and Parrot), I tried running

```
sudo update-grub
```

which returned the following errors:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map.
Found Kali GNU/Linux Rolling (kali-rolling) on /dev/sda1
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1.  Check your device.map.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda3.  Check your device.map.
Found Parrot 4.5 (4.5) on /dev/sda3
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda3.  Check your device.map.
```

Mint and Windows were detected with no errors being returned. The GRUB manual page indeed suggested editing device.map (https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Device-map.html), which I do not know how to do (and I also could not find the file in /boot/grub/, it does not appear to be present in GRUB 2 anymore), I also did not understand the instructions at https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Device-map.html. I also searched various forums, which e.g suggested deleting grub.cfg and let it be regenerated by updating grub again or running

```
 sudo grub-mkdevicemap
```

All of this did not work.

A comment asked for the output of lsblk, so here it is:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 157,2M  1 loop /snap/brave/58
loop1    7:1    0  91,1M  1 loop /snap/core/6531
loop2    7:2    0 152,7M  1 loop /snap/brave/44
loop3    7:3    0  34,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
loop4    7:4    0 155,5M  1 loop /snap/brave/57
loop5    7:5    0  89,3M  1 loop /snap/core/6673
loop6    7:6    0  34,6M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop7    7:7    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6405
loop8    7:8    0  35,3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   326G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  31,3G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 195,3G  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    0  15,9G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   549M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0 239,8G  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0 225,5G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 931,5G  0 part
```

sdc is my HDD, no OS installed there. sdb2 is Windows, sdb5 is Mint.

Comment: Please include the output of `lsblk` to your question to help give other users an idea of what your partitioning scheme is. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I have done that.

Comment: So sda should have a boot partition for both parrotos and Kali? Where is grub installed?

Comment: On sdb (which is the one that was installed while I installed Mint), as it did not work installing it to sda while I installed Kali and Parrot OS. (Kali could not install it to the MBR, while Parrot failed completely, so I had to install it without grub).

Comment: I do not have a separate boot partition, however the root partitions of Kali and Parrot are on sda1 and sda3. Swap is sda4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now managed to determine the problem on my own: I had chosen the wrong partition table type. If you want to install an OS, always partition it as MBR (called „msdos“ in GParted). Now everything works fine and I can start everything even if choosing the same drive in the UEFI.